# In android unable to open an image file from parse.com

Tags: android

Working with android unable to open an image file that have been successfully uploaded to parse. This problem is caused only when we are trying to run our app using public client key and application id.

The same code is functioning well if we try to use test cases to check the app is running or not.

Error

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>
    AccessDenied 
</Code>
<Message>
    Access Denied
</Message>
<RequestId>01D6BFFA81948B1F</RequestId>
<HostId>
HmkNDWYP2u9nOe69wBRas8SEuZR/TMdFmqUTklMJfkqU8r97szSUd/vQp3Sa0o/iM2NXTscq4cA=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Exact mismatch:python DataStructures

<Error>
 <code> AccessDenied </code>
 <Messages> Access Denied</Message>
 <RequestId>01D6BFFA81948B1F</RequestId>
 <HostId>  HmkNDWYP2u9nOe69wBRas8SEuZR/TMdFmqUTklMJfkqU8r97szSUd/vQp3Sa0o/iM2NXTscq4cA=
 </HostId>
 </Error>

Comment: Move your comment code up into your edited question and wrap with tags